# Several polymorphic associations using class_name?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to create an article which holds in_prices and out_prices (one for each country) using rails polymorphic associations and nested forms.

I have a data model which looks something like this:

```
# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :out_prices, :class_name => "Price", :as => :priceable
    has_many :in_prices, :class_name => "Price", :as => :priceable
end

# app/models/price.rb
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :priceable, :polymorphic => true
end

# db.schema for prices
create_table "prices", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "value"
    t.integer  "country_id"
    t.integer  "priceable_id"
    t.string   "priceable_type"
end
```

The article and its associations are created using a nested form like:

```
# app/views/articles/_article_form.html.erb
<%= form_for setup_article(@article) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :in_prices do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.text_field :value %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for :out_prices do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.text_field :value %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The setup_article method is a helper method to build the associations:

```
# app/helpers/articles_helper.rb
def setup_article(article)
    if article.in_prices.nil?
        # Setup one in price for each country
        Country.all.each do |country|
            article.in_prices.build(:value => 0, :country_id => country.id)
        end
    end
    if article.out_prices.nil?
        # Setup one out price for each country
        Country.all.each do |country|
            article.out_prices.build(:value => 0, :country_id => country.id)
        end
    end
    article
end
```

setup_article is needed to make sure empty price form fields (one for each country) shows up when creating a new article.

Now to the actual problem. When I edit an already created Article (which have associated in_prices and out_prices) Rails won't be able to differentiate between these different types of polymorphic associations (in_prices and out_prices). Because of this both nested form helpers renderes form fields for *all* associated prices, which isn't the desired behavior. I only want to list in_prices in the one of the nested forms, and the out_prices in the other.

How should these associations be configured to make sure rails can differentiate between the in_prices and out_prices associations in the two different nested form helpers?

**EDIT** (***SOLVED***)

A friend of mine pointed out I need to add yet another field in the prices table to flag what type of price it is. I called this field price_type and the db.schema ended up looking like this:

```
# db.schema for prices
create_table "prices", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "value"
    t.integer  "price_type"
    t.integer  "country_id"
    t.integer  "priceable_id"
    t.string   "priceable_type"
end
```

Note: Don't name this field 'type' since this is a reserved name.

The 'price_type' field can be populated either by adding a hidden field in the nested forms (less safe), or to handle it in the controller before saving the article and its associated data. I chose to add it as hidden params like:

```
# app/views/articles/_article_form.html.erb
<%= form_for setup_article(@article) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :in_prices do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.text_field :value %>
        <%= ff.text_field :price_type, :value => "in" %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for :out_prices do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.text_field :value %>
        <%= ff.text_field :price_type, :value => "out" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

To make sure the associations gets filtered correctly they need to be declared with the ':conditions' tag, like:

```
# app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :out_prices, :class_name => "Price", :as => :priceable, :conditions => { :price_type => "in" } 
    has_many :in_prices, :class_name => "Price", :as => :priceable, :conditions => { :price_type => "out" }
end
```

.. and now everything works as expected. cheers!